# Is the algebra generated by sine and cosine separating points on $[0, 2 \pi]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider an Algebra $\cal A$ generated by $\{\cos x, \sin x\}$. I was wondering does this algebra separate the points over $[0, 2\pi]$ ?

I think it is. So I'm trying to show for any two distinct points $x,y \in [0, 2 \pi]$, but $x \neq y$, there exists $f \in \cal A$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

But I can't come up with one function which do the work.
Any thought is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is wrong on $[0,2\pi]$ but, on $[0,2\pi)$, the *two* functions $\cos$ and $\sin$ are enough to separate all the points.

Comment: But $sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4))$

Comment: @voldemort Please read the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: I am wondering how $\sin$ and $\cos$ separates all points?

Comment: Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: @voldemort Let $\mathcal F=\{\cos,\sin\}\subset\mathcal A$, then, for every $x\ne y$ in $[0,2\pi)$, there exists $f$ in $\mathcal F$ such that $f(x)\ne f(y)$. Thus $\mathcal F$ is *separating*.

Comment: Ah- don't know what caused the brain freeze